# Dynamics AX Programatically Refer to Query Fields in View

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, sql-view

To create a view method to generate a computed column, you use some code like this:

```
private static server str createMySqlScript()
{
    str cellName = SysComputedColumn::returnField(tableStr(MyViewName), identifierStr(MyDataSourceName), fieldStr(TableName, ColumnName));
    return strFmt('LEFT(%1, 5)', cellName);
}
```

Works great for regular views, with regular data sources.

However, when you use a View with a query source, instead of traditional data sources, the entire thing falls apart.

```
On the first line: "Stack trace: The method has been called with an invalid number of parameters."
```

Anyone know how to call the name of a query field instead of a datasource field in a view?

Comment: Do you have an *UNION* view?

Comment: The query referenced by the view does use UNION.  Does that change how you call the returnField() method?

Answer (score 0):

The code of `returnField` reads:

```
public static client server str returnField(TableName _viewName, str _dataSourceName, FieldName _fieldName)
{
    DictView dictView = new DictView(tableName2id(_viewName));
    return dictView.computedColumnString(_dataSourceName ,_fieldName, FieldNameGenerationMode::FieldList);
}
```

The second argument of the method must reference a valid datasource name:

> The name of the data source on the view that contains the field which value is used as a return value.

Also for a union query it must be the first datasource in the query. By default query datasource names are appended and `_1` suffix, the full name of the datasource including the suffix must be provided in the second argument.
See the view for the correct name; the view fields will have that name in the `Datasource` property.

Beware that the intrinsic function `identifierStr` has no way to validate the input argument as opposed to other functions like `tableStr`.

Answer (score 0):

For views based on union queries, an integer parameter is passed to the computed column methods:

```
private static server str createMySqlScript(int iDatasource) {
str cellName = SysComputedColumn::returnField(tableStr(MyViewName), identifierStr(MyDataSourceName), fieldStr(TableName, ColumnName));
return strFmt('LEFT(%1, 5)', cellName);
}
```

If you do not define this parameter, strange things will happen...
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg846293.aspx